# Set current date to input[type=date] in meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to set a date input field to the current date:

```
Template.something.onRendered(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateString = today.format("yyyy-MM-dd");
    $('#age').val(dateString);
});

<template name="something">
    <input type="date" id="age">
</template>
```

But this doesn't work and I don't see, what I'm doing wrong...

I'm getting the error `Exception from Tracker afterFlush function`

Comment: Eh - can you format a `Date()` like that... `(new Date()).format("yyyy-MM-dd")` returns `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things that could be preventing that code from working.

Firstly, `.format()` comes from moment.js, unless you've got your own `.format()` method set, or you're using some other library. I'm going to assuming you're using moment. So first up you'll need to ensure that you're loading moment.js.

Secondly, you can't use `.format()` on the Date object directly. Instead, you need to do it like this:

```
moment(today).format();
```

Finally, the date string is case sensitive. So `"yyyy-MM-dd"` won't work. You need to use all uppercase: `"YYYY-MM-DD"`

```
moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

This and more is covered in the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: @user3142695 You can, but not with the `.format()` method. That comes from moment. To be honest, I'd recommend using moment to format dates; it deals will all the browser inconsistencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, formatting is off, gotta use moment.

Second, make sure the `#age` element is in the dom `if ($('#age').length > 0) $('#age').val(dateString);`

As long as you format your date right, everything should be okay